# Why my Pure.css submenu is not showing on click?

Tags: html, css, pure-css

According to the [Pure.css documentation](http://purecss.io/menus/#vertical-menu-with-submenus), a dropdown menu should appear when I click on `Option3`, but it doesn't. Why is it?

```css
.custom-restricted-width {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.1/build/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="menu">
  <div class="pure-menu custom-restricted-width">
    <a class="pure-menu-heading" href="index.html">Title</a>
    <ul class="pure-menu-list">
      <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Mune item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-has-children">
        <a href="#" id="menuLink1" class="pure-menu-link">Menu item 2</a>
        <ul class="pure-menu-children">
          <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Submenu item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Submenu item 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution after reading the document again:

> We recommend enabling submenus **via JavaScript** to enable
>   accessibility. To help get you started, [an example script](http://purecss.io/js/menus.js) written
>   in vanilla JS provides ARIA support, limited submenu arrow-key
>   navigation, and the ability to dismiss menus with an outside event or
>   the ESC key.

So if you download the example script above and include it with `<script src="js/dropdown.js"></script>` or something alike, the dropdown menu would work as expected.

```js
(function(window, document) {
  'use strict';

  // Enable drop-down menus in Pure
  // Inspired by YUI3 gallery-simple-menu by Julien LeComte
  // [https://github.com/yui/yui3-gallery/blob/master/src/gallery-simple-menu/js/simple-menu.js]

  function PureDropdown(dropdownParent) {

    var PREFIX = 'pure-',
      ACTIVE_CLASS_NAME = PREFIX + 'menu-active',
      ARIA_ROLE = 'role',
      ARIA_HIDDEN = 'aria-hidden',
      MENU_OPEN = 0,
      MENU_CLOSED = 1,
      MENU_PARENT_CLASS_NAME = 'pure-menu-has-children',
      MENU_ACTIVE_SELECTOR = '.pure-menu-active',
      MENU_LINK_SELECTOR = '.pure-menu-link',
      MENU_SELECTOR = '.pure-menu-children',
      DISMISS_EVENT = (window.hasOwnProperty &&
        window.hasOwnProperty('ontouchstart')) ?
      'touchstart' : 'mousedown',

      ARROW_KEYS_ENABLED = true,

      ddm = this; // drop down menu

    this._state = MENU_CLOSED;

    this.show = function() {
      if (this._state !== MENU_OPEN) {
        this._dropdownParent.classList.add(ACTIVE_CLASS_NAME);
        this._menu.setAttribute(ARIA_HIDDEN, false);
        this._state = MENU_OPEN;
      }
    };

    this.hide = function() {
      if (this._state !== MENU_CLOSED) {
        this._dropdownParent.classList.remove(ACTIVE_CLASS_NAME);
        this._menu.setAttribute(ARIA_HIDDEN, true);
        this._link.focus();
        this._state = MENU_CLOSED;
      }
    };

    this.toggle = function() {
      this[this._state === MENU_CLOSED ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    };

    this.halt = function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    };

    this._dropdownParent = dropdownParent;
    this._link = this._dropdownParent.querySelector(MENU_LINK_SELECTOR);
    this._menu = this._dropdownParent.querySelector(MENU_SELECTOR);
    this._firstMenuLink = this._menu.querySelector(MENU_LINK_SELECTOR);

    // Set ARIA attributes
    this._link.setAttribute('aria-haspopup', 'true');
    this._menu.setAttribute(ARIA_ROLE, 'menu');
    this._menu.setAttribute('aria-labelledby', this._link.getAttribute('id'));
    this._menu.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
    [].forEach.call(
      this._menu.querySelectorAll('li'),
      function(el) {
        el.setAttribute(ARIA_ROLE, 'presentation');
      }
    );
    [].forEach.call(
      this._menu.querySelectorAll('a'),
      function(el) {
        el.setAttribute(ARIA_ROLE, 'menuitem');
      }
    );

    // Toggle on click
    this._link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      ddm.toggle();
    });

    // Keyboard navigation
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      var currentLink,
        previousSibling,
        nextSibling,
        previousLink,
        nextLink;

      // if the menu isn't active, ignore
      if (ddm._state !== MENU_OPEN) {
        return;
      }

      // if the menu is the parent of an open, active submenu, ignore
      if (ddm._menu.querySelector(MENU_ACTIVE_SELECTOR)) {
        return;
      }

      currentLink = ddm._menu.querySelector(':focus');

      // Dismiss an open menu on ESC
      if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        /* Esc */
        ddm.halt(e);
        ddm.hide();
      }
      // Go to the next link on down arrow
      else if (ARROW_KEYS_ENABLED && e.keyCode === 40) {
        /* Down arrow */
        ddm.halt(e);
        // get the nextSibling (an LI) of the current link's LI
        nextSibling = (currentLink) ? currentLink.parentNode.nextSibling : null;
        // if the nextSibling is a text node (not an element), go to the next one
        while (nextSibling && nextSibling.nodeType !== 1) {
          nextSibling = nextSibling.nextSibling;
        }
        nextLink = (nextSibling) ? nextSibling.querySelector('.pure-menu-link') : null;
        // if there is no currently focused link, focus the first one
        if (!currentLink) {
          ddm._menu.querySelector('.pure-menu-link').focus();
        } else if (nextLink) {
          nextLink.focus();
        }
      }
      // Go to the previous link on up arrow
      else if (ARROW_KEYS_ENABLED && e.keyCode === 38) {
        /* Up arrow */
        ddm.halt(e);
        // get the currently focused link
        previousSibling = (currentLink) ? currentLink.parentNode.previousSibling : null;
        while (previousSibling && previousSibling.nodeType !== 1) {
          previousSibling = previousSibling.previousSibling;
        }
        previousLink = (previousSibling) ? previousSibling.querySelector('.pure-menu-link') : null;
        // if there is no currently focused link, focus the last link
        if (!currentLink) {
          ddm._menu.querySelector('.pure-menu-item:last-child .pure-menu-link').focus();
        }
        // else if there is a previous item, go to the previous item
        else if (previousLink) {
          previousLink.focus();
        }
      }
    });

    // Dismiss an open menu on outside event
    document.addEventListener(DISMISS_EVENT, function(e) {
      var target = e.target;
      if (target !== ddm._link && !ddm._menu.contains(target)) {
        ddm.hide();
        ddm._link.blur();
      }
    });

  }

  function initDropdowns() {
    var dropdownParents = document.querySelectorAll('.pure-menu-has-children');
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdownParents.length; i++) {
      var ddm = new PureDropdown(dropdownParents[i]);
    }
  }

  initDropdowns();

}(this, this.document));
```

```css
.custom-restricted-width {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.1/build/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="menu">
  <div class="pure-menu custom-restricted-width">
    <a class="pure-menu-heading" href="index.html">Title</a>
    <ul class="pure-menu-list">
      <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Mune item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-has-children">
        <a href="#" id="menuLink1" class="pure-menu-link">Menu item 2</a>
        <ul class="pure-menu-children">
          <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Submenu item 1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Submenu item 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default it is set to display:none, make it visible on hover of option3

check this snippet

```css
.custom-restricted-width {
  width: 150px;
}
.pure-menu-link:hover + .pure-menu-children {

  display:block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.1/build/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="menu">
  <div class="pure-menu custom-restricted-width">
    <a class="pure-menu-heading" href="index.html">Title</a>
    <ul class="pure-menu-list">
      <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="subjects.html" class="pure-menu-link">Option1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="objective.html" class="pure-menu-link">Option2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-has-children">
        <a href="#" id="menuLink1" class="pure-menu-link">Option3</a>
        <ul class="pure-menu-children">
          <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="subjective-1.html" class="pure-menu-link">Option3-1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="subjective-2.html" class="pure-menu-link">Option3-2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```